# The product of composite numbers in the range $[m+2, 2m+2]$ is not less than $m!$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, factorial, products

If $m \in \mathbb{N}$ is a natural number, prove that

$$ m! \leq \prod\limits_{\begin{align}k = &m+2 \\ k \text{ not }& \text{prime.} \end{align}}^{2m+1}k.$$

Comment: For each prime $p\leq m$, can you count the number of times $p$ divides $m!$ and the numerator?

Comment: Use that at most every second number can be prime (regarding numbers at least 3). That's all you need to know.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, i know the formular for that, i think it is called Legendre's Theorem with the sum of n divided by p^k rounded off

Comment: What about an induction?

Comment: @Andrew Your change, while equivalent to the original question, has made my answer below not make sense.  Please pay attention to answers when changing question statements.

Comment: @FriederJäckel Thanks for your advice. I was able to prove it now.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm sorry about that. I didn't think it'd be such a big change. I'll try to pay more attention in the future. In case there is a next time, please feel free to revert or improve my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the binomial coefficient $\binom{2m+1}m$ is an integer, and 
$$\binom{2m+1}m=\frac{(2m+1)!}{m!(m+1)!}=\frac 1{m!}\prod_{k=m+2}^{2m+1}k$$
Here comes the number-theory part: we know $m!(m+1)!$ divides $(2m+1)!$, and since no primes $p>m+1$ is divisible by the donominator $m!(m+1)!$, we see that $m!(m+1)!$ divides $(2m+1)!/(\text{products of all primes between m+2 and 2m+1})$. The result follows.

Answer (score 1):

There has been an edit to the question that makes this answer hard to understand.  The original version of the question asked:
$$
\frac{\displaystyle\prod_{k=m+2\\k\text{ not prime}}^{2m+1}k}{m!}\geq 1.
$$

Sketch:

- Assume that $p$ is a prime such that $p\leq m$.
- The number of times that $p$ divides $m!$ is computed by:
  $$
  \sum_{i=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{m}{p^i}\right\rfloor
  $$
- The number of times that $p$ divides the numerator is
  $$
  \sum_{i=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{2m+1}{p^i}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{m+1}{p^i}\right\rfloor
  $$
  It is the same as the number of times that $p$ divides $\frac{(2m+1)!}{(m+1)!}$ since this quotient, when compared to the given quotient, only includes extra primes and $p$ can't divide any of those.
- Observe that the number of powers of $p$ in the quotient is
  $$
  \sum_{i=1}^\infty\left\lfloor\frac{2m+1}{p^i}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{m+1}{p^i}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{m}{p^i}\right\rfloor
  $$
- Since each term in the sum is nonnegative, some nonnegative number of $p$'s divide the quotient.  Therefore, the given quotient is an integer (which is greater than or equal to $1$).